# Как сделать блок на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

Как сделать блок с фото на всю ширину экрана, чтобы он при разрешении `(1400*715)` был на всю ширину (при разрешении меньше чем `1600*816`, фото выходят за пределы). Или наоборот,- если фотографий будет меньше, чтобы они также подстраивались под размер.

```css
.row-t {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.row-t img {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio-b">
  <div class="row-t">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: Сейчас это всё выглябит так]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если предполагать, что картинки у Вас всегда будут одинакового размера, то можно с помощью js задавать им ширину и высоту в процентах в зависимости от их количества:

```js
var len = $('.row-t img').length;
$('.row-t img').each(function(){
  $(this).css({'width':100/len+'%','height':100/len+'%' });
});

$('button').click(function(){
  $('.row-t img:last').remove();
  var len2 = $('.row-t img').length;
  $('.row-t img').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'width':100/len2+'%','height':100/len2+'%' });
  });
});
```

```css
.row-t {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.row-t img {
    opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="portfolio-b">
  <div class="row-t">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/14/c867783e4b3e7077242a8ebff55662bc-full.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
<br />
<button>Убрать одну картинку</button>
```

Comment: Круто но можешь подсказать как сделать что бы эта функция влияла только на этот блок с картинками?

Comment: @BraFik, в смысле - "влияла на блок"?

Comment: просто эта функция, влияет и на другие картинки которые у меня в вёрстке

Comment: @BraFik, слишком глупый вопрос))

Comment: @St1myL В какойм смысле, я просто почти не разбираюсь в JS вот и задаю

Comment: @BraFik, а тут в js не надо разбираться - это чистый css: надо лишь уточнить селектор (в данном случае не просто img, а .row-t img) я поправил ответ

Comment: @humster_spb Тебе может показатся что я голову морочу, но теперь у меня почему-то картинки стали очень маленькими. И не на всю ширину

Comment: @BraFik, ну, ты мой пример ведь видишь? он же на всю ширину, правда? значит, у тебя там в вёрстке что-то ещё на что-то влияет...